# Cannot redeclare content_width() wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting the error `<<Cannot redeclare content_width()>>` in woocommerce wordpress after loading a page via ajax.

Comment: You probably have a plugin that defines a function with the same name as woocommerce (or maybe a different plugin entirely). I would disable all plugins one by one until that error goes away.

Comment: Thanks Kodos. Yes, you was right there is plugin "Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider" which make this error. But I need this plugin. How I can make it works with plugin?

Comment: You would probably have to modify that plugin. Look for `function content_width(...)` and rename it to something like `function content_width_2(...)` and then rename all instances of `content_width` to `content_width_2`. Do this only for that plugin ("Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider")

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable modifying that plugin directly, you could copy that plugin and then naming the copy "Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider Custom" and making all your changes in there.